# Determine which of the folowing statements hold: $f(x) = O(g(x))$, $f(x) = o(g((x))$, $g(x) = o(f(x))$, $g(x) = O(f(x))$ when $x → ∞$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

Determine which of the folowing statements hold: $f(x) = O(g(x))$, $f(x) = o(g((x))$, $g(x) = o(f(x))$, $g(x) = O(f(x))$ when $x → ∞$:

a) $f(x) = e^x$, $g(x)= e^\sqrt{x}$

b) $f(x) =e^{log_2^2 x}$ , $g(x) = x^2$.

I know that for a, only $g(x) = o(f(x))$ holds, and for b, $f(x) = O(g(x))$, $f(x) = o(g(x))$ and $g(x) = O(f((x))$ hold as $x → ∞$ using a calculator.

I wonder how we prove these points using the formal definition of big-O-notation (and small-O-notation), that is:

(i) $f(x) = O(g(x))$ when there exists $C > 0$ such that $f(x) ≤ Cg(x)$ when $x → ∞$ ($X = ∞$ here)

( (ii) $f(x) = o(g(x))$ when $\lim_{x \to +\infty} {f(x) \over g(x)} =0)$

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question easier to read.

Comment: Doesn't $g(x) = o(f(x))$ imply $g(x) = O(f(x))$?

Comment: @GregMartin so $g(x) = o(f(x))$ always imply $g(x)) =$O$(f(x))$? This is quite new to me.

Comment: Fair enough—try showing that implication directly from the definitions of $O$ and $o$, it's a good exercise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we need exact definition (considering $x \to +\infty$ for non negative functions):
$$O(g)=\{\phi \colon, \exists C>0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x> \delta, \phi(x) \leqslant C g(x)  \}$$
so, if we consider $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=e^\sqrt{x}$, then having $\sqrt{x} \leqslant x$ for $x>1$, immediately gives $e^\sqrt{x} \in O(e^x)$ for $C=\delta=1$.

For little-$o$
$$o(g)=\{\phi \colon, \exists \varepsilon(x), \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\varepsilon(x)=0 , \exists \delta >0, \forall x> \delta, \phi(x) = \varepsilon(x)g(x)  \}$$
now using representation $e^\sqrt{x} =e^{-x+\sqrt{x}} e^x$ and knowing $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}e^{-x+\sqrt{x}}=0$ we have $e^\sqrt{x} \in o(e^x),x \to +\infty$.

Of course, as rightly indicated in  the  Greg Martin's comment, you can obtain first from second, because $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\varepsilon(x)=0$  gives $\exists C>0$ such that $\varepsilon(x) \leqslant C$.

Comment: So as long as $ f(x) < g(x) $, then $ f(x) = O(g(x)) $ ?

Comment: Of course. But to be in $O(g)$ is less restrictive, then simply to be less then $g$ for all $x$. $O(g)$ is more "intellectual", more flexible, then simple inequality. Feel free to ask more when/if you'll need it.